# How does golang knows that no new value is going to be given to channel?

Tags: go, asynchronous, concurrency, channel, goroutine

After printing 1 2 3 4 5 , this code goes to deadlock. (after producer has stopped producing from for loop)

```golang
func producer(n int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            c <- i
        }
    }()
    return c
}

func consumer(r <-chan int) {
    for {
        val := <-r
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := producer(5)
    consumer(r)
}
```

So What I understood is in consumer, channel is blocked on reading, but how does golang knows that no new value is going to be written in the channel from producer?

I mean If I change my producer like this:

```golang
func producer(n int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            c <- i
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
        c <- 6
    }()
    return c
}
```

Then after writing from for loop, it waits for 10 seconds and then writes 6 to the channel and consumer prints it, and then it goes to deadlock again.

I mean what is that one thing that tells Go Lang that nothing is going to be written on channel after this point and declare it a deadlock? is it because we returned from the producer anonymous function?

Comment: It just knows based on the fact that __all__ goroutines are blocking on a channel. If there is no running goroutine, its impossible that something writes to a channel.

Answer (score 1):

The producer needs to call `close(c)` when it’s done producing.

Not that your consumer will not halt, however, it will keep printing `0`.

You want to change producer to be:

```
func producer(n int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    return c
}
```

And you want consumer to be:

```
func consumer(r <-chan int) {
    for val := range r {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```